# Removing the power source to a brake light

Tags: vw, tail-lights, bulbs

Pretty much the title. The car is a Volkswagen Golf Variant and was built in 2014. This image is of the left tail light, behind the cover. I can't seem to get the holder for the power cord loose. The hole above the cord was where the bolt to keep the light in place sat.

.
[image]

I tried pushing and pulling the red button, pushing the black top down, there is no room to twist the bulb sideways and the power cord doesn't extend beyond the hole. I tried loosening the cord so it was longer but couldn't without forcing it. I would like to make sure I'm not doing something wrong before forcing the cord or the holder. Most tutorials go over clipping it off quickly and I can't figure out how they do it.

Comment: Slide the red tab out but do not remove, now you can depress the release tab.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! As Moab said, with the addition of, the release tab he's talking about is just behind the red tab. Press it down and wiggle the connector ... it shouldn't be *too hard* to remove it.